# Cannot resolve 'getSupportActionBar()'

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make a navigationDrawer but i am having problem with the portion getSupportActionBar(). It is showing - cannot resolve method 'getSupportActionBar()'. I don't know why. Please someone help me. Below is my code for DrawerActivity

```
package com.example.rahulshaw.medizy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

List<DrawerItem> dataList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // Initializing
    dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    // Add Drawer Item to dataList
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Home", R.drawable.ic_home));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile", R.drawable.icon_profile));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("My Bookings", R.drawable.ic_bookings));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Services", R.drawable.ic_services));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Refer-Earn", R.drawable.ic_share));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Medizy Money", R.drawable.ic_medizy_money));
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Call us", R.drawable.ic_call));
       /* dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camera", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
                    R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));*/
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_about));
        /*dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));*/
    dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_help));

    adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
            dataList);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()

        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        SelectItem(0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
    return true;
}

public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch (possition) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 11:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 12:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
    setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        SelectItem(position);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Activity to AppCompatActivity, it will resolve your issue as getSupportActionBar() is supported by AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Solved the issue and new issue arised. Now it is showing ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.activity, android.support.v7.widget.toolbar, android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout, android.graphics,drawable.Drawable & android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.DrawerToggle  java.lang.integer,int, int) is not public in ' android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle'.Cannot be accessed from outside the package.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity
```

with this :

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

and if you dont have appcompat library in your gradle file add this to your app build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Aakash said, change Activity to AppCompatActivity. You also need to declare the toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

and then you can access it by:

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

Comment: Do i have to create xml layout for toolbar?

Comment: You can either put it the activity's layout and give it the id, or you can create a seperate xml layout and then place it in your activity's layout using <include>.